# clicking on some text in mocha JS

Tags: javascript, click, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on some text, with no link in it. but i keep getting this error, which is normal:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (692, 244). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-footer">...</div>
```

is there a way to click on a "passive" element?

thanks for helping.

Comment: The problem is not that the element is "passive", but that there is another element (another label, an image, etc.) on top of it--so your text is, in fact, unclickable.

Comment: Oh okay. and is there any solution to bypass that?
This problem happen after clicking on a select field in a form.

Comment: When you go through the same steps manually, is the text element visible?

Comment: Yes. in fact, i'm just trying to unlock a button, that stay disabled until i click somewhere out of the select field. But i can't because it's on top of everything... I just noticed that i can press tab key to do the same, so i'm working on it. I will try to find how to do it, but the selenium doc is a real pain for newbies like me.... Thank you anyway for helping!

Comment: Hmm... ok, but let me rephrase: is the text element covered maybe by another layer? I would try using your browser's dev tools to check if there's another element on top. I'd recommend Firefox's 3D view.

Comment: So I used the 3D tool.
on the top I have some text, the select field, and 2 buttons: one to close and the other to validate (which is disabled).
I guess I will go for the top text until the bug of the disabled button is corrected. thank you.